# Golang fmt printf right padding

Tags: go

I have this code to create a pyramid of numbers and zeroes based on the given inputs.

```
inputs := []int{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
for idx, input := range inputs {
    fmt.Printf("%0*d\n", len(inputs)-idx, input)
}
```

Which outputs:
0000001
000003
00004
0005
006
07
9

But the designated output is:
1000000
300000
40000
5000
600
70
9

how can I achieve that? when I tried the "%0-*d\n" it only pad the spaces and the zeroes does not appear.

Comment: try `fmt.Printf("%d\n", input * int(math.Pow(10, float64(len(inputs)-idx-1))))`

Comment: "300000" is **not** a right-padded formating of 3. fmt.Printf **cannot** do this as it does formating only. Convert your ints to strings and pad those strtings at the right with 0s.

Answer (score 2):

nvm i did it with my idiom way

```
fmt.Printf("%d%0*d\n", input, len(inputs)-idx-1, 0)
```

Comment: output i got from this `1000000 300000 40000 5000 600 70 90`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the idea!
But myself would prefer using empty string, easier to get number of zeros right.

```golang
    inputs := []int{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
    for idx, input := range inputs {
        fmt.Printf("%d%0*s\n", input, len(inputs)-idx-1, "")
    }
```

Which gives

```
1000000
300000
40000
5000
600
70
9
```